# How to remove \r from json?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run the following

```
let res = e.target.result.split('\n').map(line => line.split(','));
var myData = $("#dvCSV").text(JSON.stringify(res, null, '  '));
myData = myData.replace("\r", " ");
$("#dvCSV").append(myData);
```

But I still get \r in the output

```
[
  [
    "New York",
    "Employee",
    "20\r"
  ],
  [
    "Singapore",
    "Employee",
    "15"
  ]
```

Comment: You're using both "\r" and "/r" in your question, "\r" has special meaning (escape for a return character) which one do you really mean? It appears you're trying to remove the "\r" strings from the JSON output but it's not clear from your question.

Comment: `split('\r\n')` in first line

Comment: @hyphenthis yup, updated thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash, and do the replace at the `stringify`, where it is a string

```
JSON.stringify(res, null, '  ').replace("\\r", " ");
```

Stack snippet sample

```js
var res = [
  [
    "New York",
    "Employee",
    "20\r"
  ],
  [
    "Singapore",
    "Employee",
    "15"
  ]
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, '  ').replace("\\r", " ") )
```

Comment: still having /r

Comment: myData isn't a string to start with

Comment: @rob.m Updated ... missed that `myData` wasn't a string

Answer (score 0):

replace method only removes first instance. in your case, only first instance of "\r"

Comment: so how can I remove /r?

Comment: Use can you regex in place of that, but you can also do myData.split("/r").join(""); This happens for strings

Comment: try: myData.replace(/\r/g, '');

Comment: @tpaul The following worked for me: myData.replace(/\\r/g, "")

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse and stringify together, like

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
```